# Excel count if used with data validation gives 0 each time

Tags: excel, validation, countif

I am using the countif function to count the number of times the word "yes" occurs in a range. The range only accepts "yes" and "no" values through data validation from a list. The result is always 0 irrespective of what values I give the range. Any help?

Comment: =countif(G7:G13, "YES")

Comment: G7:G13 only take yes or no through data validation

Comment: `G7:G13 only take yes or no` check additional trailing/leading spaces and also try `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(TRIM(G7:G13)="YES"))`

Comment: Show your data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, it seems that range `G7:G13` contains `"yes"`/`"no"` with additional leading/trailing spaces. Try next formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(TRIM(G7:G13)="YES"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using wildcards

`=COUNTIF(G7:G13,"*YES*")`